# How to add asterisk to a list of filenames and then make it a line using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I’ve a list of file names (about 4000).

Example:

A-67569 H-67985 J-87657 K-85897 so on...

[image]

Note that there is a space between filenames.

I'm trying to do this with Notepad++

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by a line format? Please [edit] the question and provide a properly formatted before and after example.

Answer (score 0):

Go to find/replace and switch search mode to regular expression, then in <kbd>Find what</kbd> put this

```
([A-Z]-\d+)
```

and to field <kbd>Replace with</kbd>

```
\*\1\*
```

then fire <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

P.S.
If you want everything in one single line then after running first replacement, run this, - in <kbd>find what</kbd> `\r?\n` and in <kbd>replace with</kbd> remove all characters
and run again <kbd>Replace all</kbd>